# Mysterious "Missing Template"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know if there is a better way to do this than to simply link to my (very small) rails app on Githb... https://github.com/MaxPleaner/someapp

The issue right not is a weird "missing template" error at /notes/new 
I made a corresponding view so I'm not sure why this step is making an error. 
The view is called 'new.html.erb' and the link is written like this:

```
<%= link_to "link text...", :controller => "notes", :action => "new" %>
```

The error says -

```
Template is missing
Missing template notes/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/macs/Desktop/playapp/app/app/views" * "/home/macs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.8/app/views"
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new.html is in the wrong folder.  You have it in views/notes/new.html.erb  Move that into *app*/views/notes/new.html.erb